# How to make a place finder request with Facebook SDK V5

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to make a Facebook request that allow me to retrieve a page which is refered to a place using the `sendRequest()` in PHP Facebook SDK V5 but I don't know what to fill in the `params` array. Here's my example :

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook($config);
$params = array(
     //some code here ! 
);

 $response = $fb->sendRequest('get','/search?q=%s&type=place',$params);

 var_dump($reponse);
```

So I need your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the soulution here's it :

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook($config);
$params = array(

     'q' => "resorante del arte paris",
     'limit' => 20,
);

 $response = $fb->sendRequest('get','/search?type=place',$params);
```

Thanks for those who doesn't reply or make me a negative vote!